How to perform a cumulative sum with conditional selection based on another column in Polars?
I have a DataFrame and I want to get the latest goals scored by teams in this cluster to apply an ewm_mean(), that is, create aEWM_COLUMN like the example below:
Original Table



Season
Wk
Home
Away
HomeGoals
AwayGoals
Cluster_home
Cluster_away
Cluster_pair_key




2024
27.0
teamA
teamF
3
2
4
1
1_4


2024
27.0
teamB
teamG
1
3
2
2
2_2


2024
27.0
teamC
teamH
1
0
5
3
3_5


2024
27.0
teamD
teamI
0
1
3
1
1_3


2024
27.0
teamE
teamJ
3
0
3
4
3_4



Looking at teamE, I wanted to take into account the Home Goals of team E, the Home goals of teamD, and the AwayGoals of teamC. I created the Cluster_pair_key_Organized column because I thought it could help in some way.
New Table



Season
Wk
Home
Away
HomeGoals
AwayGoals
Cluster_home
Cluster_away
Cluster_pair_key
EWM_COLUMN




2024
27.0
teamA
teamF
3
2
4
1
1_4
3 * 0.8 + ...


2024
27.0
teamB
teamG
1
3
2
2
2_2
1 * 0.8 + ...


2024
27.0
teamC
teamH
1
0
5
3
3_5
0 * 0.8 + ...


2024
27.0
teamD
teamI
0
1
3
1
1_3
0 * 0.8 + 0.2 * 0 + ...


2024
27.0
teamE
teamJ
3
0
3
4
3_4
3 * 0.8 + 0.2 * (0 * 0.8 + 0.2 * 0)




can you provide a minimal reproducible example and your expected output?

My expected output is the EWM_COLUMN, the original Dataframe. The original dataframe does not have this column.

@Pedro_Siqueira I suggest to remove all non-relevant columns from the input and make clear how output should be calculated

This is a polars question, but check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples anyways.

Can you show an example where teamE appears multiple times as the Home team? And also show a column with the actual final ewm_mean value?

df_ewm = (
    df
    .select(
        Team=pl.concat_list("Home","Away"),
        Goals=pl.concat_list("HomeGoals","AwayGoals"),
        Cluster=pl.concat_list("Cluster_home","Cluster_away"),
    )
    .explode(pl.all())
    .select(
        pl.col.Team,
        EWM_COLUMN = pl.col.Goals.ewm_mean(alpha=0.8, adjust=False).over("Cluster")
    )
)

df.join(df_ewm, left_on="Home", right_on="Team")

shape: (5, 9)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───┬───────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬────────────┐
│ Season ┆ Wk  ┆ Home  ┆ Away  ┆ … ┆ AwayGoals ┆ Cluster_home ┆ Cluster_away ┆ EWM_COLUMN │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆   ┆ ---       ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆   ┆ i64       ┆ i64          ┆ i64          ┆ f64        │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══╪═══════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ teamA ┆ teamF ┆ … ┆ 2         ┆ 4            ┆ 1            ┆ 3.0        │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ teamB ┆ teamG ┆ … ┆ 3         ┆ 2            ┆ 2            ┆ 1.0        │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ teamC ┆ teamH ┆ … ┆ 0         ┆ 5            ┆ 3            ┆ 1.0        │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ teamD ┆ teamI ┆ … ┆ 1         ┆ 3            ┆ 1            ┆ 0.0        │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ teamE ┆ teamJ ┆ … ┆ 0         ┆ 3            ┆ 4            ┆ 2.4        │
└────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴───┴───────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴────────────┘


